# Loading a laravel 8 + vue component only with the SHIFT key

Tags: laravel, vue.js, components

I am starting a project with laravel 8 + vue.

My app.js file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPOmX.png)

My index.blade.php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfk2K.png)

Unfortunately the component is not loading. If I press the SHIFT key - everything works fine.

vue is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFgRS.png)

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. If I press the SHIFT key everything loads very nicely.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqPBF.png)

Please. Help.

Comment: I think it is because you are not using a Vue shared instance. Calling new Vue() here will setup new instance, so you loose all component registrations.

Comment: But on the developer station it works for me. I don't have any problems on the development station.